# Horizontally draggable quasar q-cards using vue.draggable.next

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, draggable, quasar-framework

I've seen a few 'solutions' online about this but to no avail for us. We're working with the quasar framework and trying to setup a horizontally wrapped set of that are are draggable (for re-ordering). Below is the basic stub of the code we're working with to get this going. However, we're not able to get the cards to layout horizontally everything is stacked in a list. What are we doing wrong?

```
<template>
  <draggable
    v-model="items"
    group="items"
    direction="horizontal"
    item-key="id"
    @start="drag = true"
    @end="drag = false"
  >
    <template #item="{ element }">
      <q-card class="card">
        <q-img src="~assets/temp/bb-auto.png" :alt="`Image ${element.name}`">
          <div class="absolute-bottom text-subtitle2 text-center">
            Image {{ element.name }}
          </div>
        </q-img>
      </q-card>
    </template>
  </draggable>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import draggable from 'vuedraggable';

const drag = ref(false);

const items = ref([
  { name: 'item1' },
  { name: 'item2' },
  { name: 'item3' },
  { name: 'item4' },
  { name: 'item5' },
]);
</script>

<style scoped>
.card {
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  display: flex;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out our overall structure was incorrect and once we sorted that out was able to back this into the draggable. We then had to basically treat our  as the row.

```
<template>
  <draggable
    v-model="items"
    group="items"
    class="q-pa-md row items-start q-gutter-md"
    direction="horizontal"
    item-key="name"
    @start="drag = true"
    @end="drag = false"
  >
    <template #item="{ element }">
      <q-card class="card">
        <q-img src="~assets/temp/bb-auto.png" :alt="`Image ${element.name}`">
          <div class="absolute-bottom text-subtitle2 text-center">
            Image {{ element.name }}
          </div>
        </q-img>
      </q-card>
    </template>
  </draggable>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import draggable from 'vuedraggable';

const drag = ref(false);

const items = ref([
  { name: 'item1' },
  { name: 'item2' },
  { name: 'item3' },
  { name: 'item4' },
  { name: 'item5' },
]);
</script>

<style scoped>
.card {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  display: flex;
}
</style>
```